# OPenCV : How to get the perimeter coordinates around image

Tags: python, opencv

Looking to extract the polyline perimeter around this image in x,y coordinates using Python and Opencv
[image]

This what I have done so far
def api():

```
# Reading image 
# variable and converting to gray scale. 
img = cv2.imread('floorplan.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Converting image to a binary image 
# ( black and white only image). 
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(img, 110, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 

# Detecting contours in image. 
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
all = []
for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) <= 200 :
       continue    
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255,0), 2)
    center = (x,y)
    all.append(center)
print(all)
```

Comment: The content of each contour c you get from cv2.findContours is stored as a vector of points. Are those the points you are looking for?

Comment: @CarlosMelus yes. the points of the largest contour around the whole floorplan

Comment: Get the external contours not the tree and find the largest one by area. See contourArea. `big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I approached your problem is by trying to threshold the whole perimeter you are looking for. To do that, I found the background color in the image and used it to filter the original image and erode the selection to make it slightly bigger and remove some of the artifacts.
Then, similar to your code, find the contours, remove smaller contours and approximate each one to a polygon. Once you have that approximation, you can simply draw it as a contour, which is very efficient.
To calculate the approximation I use 3% difference with the original contour perimeter, calculated as: `cv2.arcLength(c, True)` for each contour.

```
mask = cv2.inRange(img, np.array([240, 240, 240]), np.array([244, 244, 244]))
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
newmask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(~newmask, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

output = np.zeros_like(img[:, :, 0])
for c in [c for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) > 200]:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03*cv2.arcLength(c, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(output, [approx], -1, 255, 2)
plt.imshow(output, 'gray')
```

[image: Result of the code above]

Comment: Thanks CarlosMelus. can you clarify what the newmask is used for? also is the contours variable defined the same as the original example I provided above?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I forgot to add the `findContours` operation that now is done on the newmask array.

Comment: Thank you, Sorry about the noob question, how do I get the polyline in X,Y like this [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]...[Xn,Yn]]

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain more carefully. The variable `approx` contains the points of the polyline in the format you're expecting.

Comment: I tried to run it and getting an error with `cv2.inRange(img, np.array([240, 240, 240]), np.array([244, 244, 244]))` 
error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The lower boundary is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a scalar in function 'inRange'

Comment: Probably your image is grayscale, not color. The range in that case cannot have 3 components (BGR) but just 1: `cv2.inRange(img, np.array([240]), np.array([244]))`. Also, you probably need to find a range of grays that works for your image, and replace those values in the function above.